# Mozilla Firefox border overlaps

Tags: html, css, html-table, border, mozilla

I have a problem in Mozilla Firefox (58.0.2), in Chrome & Safari is working perfect. As you can see, that gray border overlaps.

That gray sidebar is a td with rowspan = 2

**Mozilla:**

[image]

**Chrome:**

[image]

haml syntax

```
%table{style: "border: none;"}
  %tbody.render_directories_table
    %tr
      %td{rowspan: 2, style: "background-color: #{color}; border: 2px solid #{color} !important;"}
        ...
      %td{colspan: 2}
        ...
    %tr
      %td
        ...
      %td
        ...
```

css:

```
.render_directories_table > tr > td
   border: 2px solid #e4e4e4 !important
   padding: 10px 5px 10px 10px !important
```

Comment: Add your code what you tried.

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would be helpful if you could let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) .